# How can I install apk that allowing only installing from google play?

Tags: google-play-store, apk

I have apk that I want to edit the assets on him and upload that back to the device. The apk downloaded originally from the google play, and I used apk extractor to get the apk of the app. 
 But when I'm trying to install the new one from apk, and not from the app store, I'm getting an error on start saying app not installed from google play store, reinstall from there. 
I put my hand on the code by revers engineering with [jadx](https://github.com/skylot/jadx).
So I know that they check by install package name and I even found the function to edit, but I can't edit because (because I don't know how to recreate the classes.dex file and I think because this is not like the real source code, I get a lot of run time errors).
I tried also `adb shell pm install -i com.android.vending -r [package name]` didn't worked...  
Does anyone know what I can do?
Thanks,
Alon.

Comment: One edits a `classes.dex` by baksmaling it and then smaling it back with ApkTool, which can deconstruct an app into assets and source code. The code is written in a low-level language called Smali, partially resembling Assembly. Editing Java or Kotlin directly is not possible.